# How to add tooltip to dropdown on mouse over in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add tooltip to dropdown list in mouse over to the list but it only displays the dropdown and even I cannot move my mouse in output. Please fix this error. The code I had tried for this jquery is

**CSS**

```
#hint{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tooltip{
    margin:8px;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:yellow;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label id="username">Username : </label><input type="text" / size="50">
```

**Script**

```
var changeTooltipPosition = function(event) {
  var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
  var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
  $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});
};

var showTooltip = function(event) {
  $('div.tooltip').remove();
  $('<div class="tooltip">I\' am tooltips! tooltips! tooltips! :)</div>')
        .appendTo('body');
  changeTooltipPosition(event);
};

var hideTooltip = function() {
   $('div.tooltip').remove();
};

$("span#hint,label#username'").bind({
   mousemove : changeTooltipPosition,
   mouseenter : showTooltip,
   mouseleave: hideTooltip
});
```

I tried this code but its useless
From a dropdown list when my mouse moves to the list it should display tooltip i.e mouseover

Comment: It would be nicer to copy the code here instead of the screenshot.

Comment: please put your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)...

Comment: added code to the fiddle

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Also include the html of your drop down. I think you would need to put all you've got here so we can see whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this simply using title attribute. Unless and until you don't want to customize. Remove the css and the related html.

```
$('#YourDropdownListId').mouseover(function() { 
$(this).attr('title','This is DropdownList'); 
})
```

If you want tooltip for the options in DropdownList. Then change the selector simply.